# I have a problem with Unity 2021.3.2f1 when I open up a new project there's lots of errors in the console this only happens in this version

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey guys so after I installed the new version of Unity(2021.3.2f1) I created a new project while it was opening up I got an error asking if I wanted to enter in safe mode or not... I ignored it and proceeded, when it opened it had the errors in the image. I tried to find a solution but I was not able to find one And this only happens in this version I think something got messed up when I previously installed the beta version before its launch the beta version had the same problem.[this is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh2uA.png)

Comment: If you installed a new version of Unity you should **1)** quit Unity **2)** delete your **Library** (internal cache) folder.  Also be sure it is not part of source control **3)** Re-open Unity and your project.  The **Library** folder is re-created.  Failing that, open in safe-mode and remove the Test Framework and/or NUnit Extensions.  This is the 2nd question in so many days with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I deleted the library folder in my project but it didn't work so I followed your next solution, I removed the test framework but it still didn't work. Is there a way to fully reset unity without loosing my projects? anyway thanks again for replying